# How do I block Unity Game Telemetry?

Tags: firewall, unity3d

It was recently announced that Unity will start charging game developers a fee for every Unity based game installed on the computer. Upon learning of this, I also learnt that Unity collects installation information from users, which in my mind is a form of telemetry data that I would rather not be giving away.

As someone who plays a lot of games, I would rather my computer was not phoning home to Unity. Which hosts do Unity Games phone home to? How can I block them from collecting telemetry in Windows Firewall?

Comment: Blocking the developer IP will likely just be a game of cat and mouse.

Comment: Good luck with that. Part of that "telemetry" is likely to be the always online anti-piracy system that is baked into almost all modern AAA titles, especially the single player games, and blocking part or all of it will probably prevent you playing the game at all. Welcome to modern gaming where even single player games don't work without an Internet connection. If you don't want this telemetry then the easier option is just not playing those games.

Comment: On top of what already has been said. Unity is dying so hard right now, I wonder if they'll even exist on januari 1st 2024. It has turned into a battle between the company Unity, the gamers, the developers and even former unity employees who have disagreed upon this so many times. Thrust has been broken to the point that I don't even think this can be fixed anymore.

Comment: There are tools such as Folder Firewall Blocker, https://sourceforge.net/directory/firewall/windows/ for Windows, that could prevent any file in a folder form "dialing out". That said, the game would likely be unplayable, by design.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?